# Arithmatic Operation based on CASE statement

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a table with Four Fields viz. ID, Dollar, Indicator and Type.

```
ID | Dollar |   Indicator | Type

1  |    30  |   1         | A

1  |    20  |   1         | A

1  |    60  |   0         | A

1  |    34  |   1         | B

1  |    23  |   0         | B

1  |    45  |   0         | B

2  |    20  |   1         | A

2  |    20  |   0         | A
```

Now I want to Add all dollar where indicator is 1 and then subtract them with dollar having indicator 0 for each id. Also In some cases they should also be grouped by Type.

I have used following code but it doesn't seems to be giving proper answer.

```
proc sql;
  select ID,Type,
  case when Indicator = '1' then sum(Dollar) else 0 end as Credit,
  case when Indicator = '0' then sum(Dollar) else 0 end as Debit
  from test
  group by ID,Type
  ;
quit;

proc sql;
  select ID,Type, (Credit - Debit) as Trans
  from test
  group by Id, Type
  ;
quit;
```

Comment: Good thing to remember with group by: everything has to be either a group by variable, or a summarization (sum, mean, count, max, min, etc.) as the _first_ part of the column definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is tagged as with SAS, so not sure if this will help.

But in your SQL you need to use SUM on the case statement, not the other way around:

```
select 
   ID,
   Type,
   sum(case when Indicator = '1' then Dollar else 0 end) as Credit,
   sum(case when Indicator = '0' then Dollar else 0 end) as Debit
from
   test
group by 
   ID,
   Type
;
```

And then do your second operation.

However you can do this all in a single SQL statement:

```
select 
   id, 
   type, 
   sum(case indicator when 1 then dollar else -1*dollar end) as net_dollar
from
   temp
group by 
   id,
   type
```

The `CASE` statement here simply changes the sign of the dollar amounts for the debit transactions, so you can then sum everything in a single step.

Comment: Works the same way in SAS's SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Below code should do the job. You need to sum the variables, though if you only want the net figure you can dump the first 2 case statements. Also, using the dollar8 format will improve the look of your output.

```
proc sql ;
  create table output as
  select id, type,
  sum(case when Indicator = '1' then Dollar else 0 end) as Credit format dollar8.,
  sum(case when Indicator = '0' then Dollar else 0 end) as Debit format dollar8.,
  sum(case when Indicator = '1' then Dollar else -1*Dollar end) as Trans format dollar8.
  from Test
  group by 1, 2
  ;
quit ;
```